# Input field goes blank when Submit is clicked

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

This is an existing Visual Studio 2003 project (written in VB). There is an input form which contains many fields including a `due date` field. This field is popultaed based on the value selected in `Reason type` dropdown and it was also editable. Recently, I had to disable the `due date` field so that the populated value could not be changed (based on the logged in user). The probelm I am facing is that when the Submit button is clicked, an IE popup window opens and the vlaue in the `due date' field just disappers and becomes blank.

```
 Private Sub btnSubmitOrdersTab_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSubmitOrdersTab.Click
        If Not Me.txtPRCEmail.Value.Length = 0 Or Not hPRCEmail.Value.Length = 0 Then
                SubmitClick()
        Else
                RegisterStartupScript("PRCEmail", "<script language=javascript>window.open (""" & CType(Application("cBaseURL"), String) & "administration/supervisors/Orders/prc_email_reason.aspx"",null,""height=200,width=400,status=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no"");</script>")
        End If
End Sub
```

I tried to get the value of the `due date` just before the `RegisterStartupScript()` function using `duedatevalue = Me.txtDueDate.Value`, but it is blank.

**Is there any way that I can prevent the `due date` field from becoming blank. This is not an issue if the `due date` field is not disabled.**

This is the Java Script function I am calling from the `onload` event of the `<body>` to disable the due date.

```
function DisableDueDate()
            {
                                    if (udisable == "true")
                    document.getElementById("divduedate").setAttribute('disabled',true);

                else
                    document.getElementById("divduedate").setAttribute('disabled',false);

            }
```

The reason I used disable is because the due date is in a `<td>` tag along with a gif next to it (not a server control), which pops up a calender when clicked so that the user can select a date. I want the entire content of the `<td>` tag disabled- including the gif.

Answer (score 0):

Use **readonly** instead of using **disabling** the textbox, if you want to read the value of the texbox on server side.

```
document.getElementById("divduedate").setAttribute('readonly',true);
```

OR

```
 document.getElementById("divduedate").readOnly=true
```

OR

Using jQuery:

```
 $('#readonly').attr("readonly", true)
```

**Disabled attribute will not allow "divduedate" to post its value to the server.**

Comment: The reason I used disable is because the due date is in a div tag along with a gif next to it (not a server control), which pops up a calender when clicked so that the user can select a date. I want the entire content of the div tag disabled- including the gif.

Answer (score 0):

In the `btnSubmitOrdersTab_Click` event you can save the value of the `due date` in a `Session`, and then in the `Page_Load` you can get the value from the `Session` and set the `due date` field with it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't set the `Enabled` property to False. Instead, use the `ReadOnly` property and set it to true.